# How to retrieve IFile from headless RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp, headless

I have a headless RCP project. I am passing an xml file as command line argument to that project. How can I retrieve IFile information from the xml file?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert a string for a fully qualified path into an IFile instance?  Is the path inside of the workspace?

Comment: Yes. The file can be in any workspace.

Comment: If the file is not inside of the currently loaded workspace, then you cannot easily convert it into an IFile instance.  There are tricks you can do, but it is not easy or straight forward.